# how to make phone number clickable in classifield wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, phone-number

I tried everything to make the phone number clickable but for some reason it didn't work

```
    <?php global $redux_demo;?>
<?php $phoneon= $redux_demo['phoneon']; ?>
<?php if($phoneon == 1){?>
    <?php $post_phone = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_phone', true);  ?>
    <?php if(!empty($post_phone)) {?>
    <li><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Phone', 'classiera' ); ?></span><?php echo $post_phone; ?></li>
```

I added this and it still didn't work :

```
<a href="tel:$post_phone"> $post_phone</a>
```

and this

```
<li><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Phone', 'classiera' ); ?></span><a href="callto://<?php echo $post_phone; ?>"><?php echo $post_phone; ?></a></li>
                        <?php }?>
```

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo $post_phone; ?>"><?php echo $post_phone; ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I change the code but now its not showing anything on the website 

      
<li><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Phone', 'classiera' ); ?></span><a href="tel:<?php echo $post_phone; ?>"><?php echo $post_phone; ?></a></li>
       <?php }?>

Answer (score 0):

Easier to do it all in PHP:

```
 <?php
      echo '<a href="tel:' . $post_phone . '">' . $post_phone . '</a>';    
      echo '<li><span>' . esc_html_e( 'Phone', 'classiera' ) . '</span><a href="callto://' . $post_phone . '">' . $post_phone . '</a>'
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i added the code but on the website it doesn't show anything for some reason

Comment: If you inspect the DOM of the Page in your browser, are the tags above there? btw. is 'classiera' a qualfied domain to retrieve your string? Maybe just leave it default..

Answer (score 0):

If your php version is greater then 5.4, then you can write it as

```
   <a href="tel:<?== $post_phone; ?>"><?= $post_phone; ?></a>
```

To check PHP version

```
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working for  you in PHP write it in HTML

```
    <a href="tel:003531234567">Call me</a>
```

If that doesnt work it is probably something to do with the phone nummber, make sure it is set up for international calling.